# How to understand this "bash" shell command

Tags: bash, shell, command, parameter-expansion

The command is:

```
[ -d $x ] && echo $x | grep "${1:-.*}"
```

I have run it separately, and `[ -d $x ] && echo $x` just outputs the directory name. What does the `${1:-.*}` mean?

Comment: what shell? that would be helpful since bash, c shell, etc all run the commands differently

Comment: bash shell on Centos

Comment: That's [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). You can find it in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script you refer to, `grep` is called. Its first argument, what
it will search for, is either the first script parameter `$1`, if one
was given, or `.*`, which matches anything, if no parameters were given.

`"$1"` or `"${1}"` in a bash script is replaced with the first argument
the script was called with. Sometimes it's necessary to process that
string a little, which can be done with shell parameter expansion, as
Etan Reisner helpfully pointed out. `:-` is one such tool; there are
several others.

`"${1:-.*}"` means "if parameter 1 is unset or null (i.e., no such
parameter was given), then substitute the part after `:`; in this case,
`.*`.

Example script `pe`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
printf 'parameter count = %d\n' $#
printf 'parameter 1 is "%s"\n' "$1"
printf 'parameter 1 is "%s"\n' "${1:-(not given)}"
```

Output:

```
$ ./pe 'foo bar'
parameter count = 1
parameter 1 is "foo bar"
parameter 1 is "foo bar"

$ ./pe
parameter count = 0
parameter 1 is ""
parameter 1 is "(not given)"
```